# there is an error in a plugin called Terawallet

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I don't want the customers to be able to buy with a negative balance but the thing is if a customer has for example 20$ in their wallet and they ordered from 2 devices a product that cost the same amount in their wallet and order in the exact moment the orders will be completed and the balance will be -20$.

I tried to add this filter

add_filter('woo_wallet_disallow_negative_transaction', '__return_true', 1);
add_filter('woo_wallet_payment_is_available', '__return_true');

but it doesn't work

Comment: Your plugin will need to implement MySQL's transactions to prevent this sort of issue. Those filters won't stop this from happening.

Comment: I used the code that you provided and it worked for me. could you update woocommerce, WordPress and the plugin to the latest version?